# bitmap rotation makes the image bigger each time is executed

Tags: java, android, matrix, bitmap

i have this simple function:

```
  private Bitmap rotateImg(Bitmap b){       
    Matrix bMat = new Matrix();
    bMat.preRotate(30, b.getWidth()/2, b.getHeight()/2);
    return Bitmap.createBitmap(b, 0, 0, b.getWidth(), b.getHeight(), bMat,false);
}
```

and is executed like this:

```
    currentStateImg = rotateImg(currentStateImg);
```

for some reason, the first time it runs, works perfectly, but each time is executed, it rotate the bitmap, but also make the image bigger (leaving blank space around it), till the VM run out of memory.

i already tried with:

```
  postRotate
  preRotate
  setRotate
  setting the last element of createBitmap (filter) to true/false
  returning a copy of the resulted bitmap from createBitmap so i could apply the config Config.ARGB_8888
```

the weird thing, is that i also tried this code:

```
 RectF r = new RectF(0,0,b.getWidth(),b.getHeight());
 bMat.mapRect(r);
```

and in the second run, the matrix calculations (the values of r.width() and r.height()) are returning a bigger image size already each time is executed, so seems to be a problem of the matrix values and not related to the createBitmap() function

anyone has some idea of what could be the problem? what value i should change so i can rotate the bitmap any amount of times i need?

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Get a piece of paper, put your phone on it (I assume it is rectangular), draw a rectangle that completely contains your phone. Now rotate it and draw a rectangle again - it is larger because phone diagonal is longer than its height or width. So while your image remains the same, the bounding rectangle becomes larger and the bitmap also has to grow.

Comment: i know that, but the dimensions are almost duplicating the size of the original image, adding blank space around it, this is not the proportional grow that happens when you rotate an object.

Comment: Blank spaces is your growing bounding rectangle. If your linear dimensions increase by sqrt(2), bitmap size doubles.